# Infinite limit of trigonometric series

Tags: trigonometry

The value of $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sin^4x+\frac{1}{4}\sin^4(2x)+\cdots+\frac{1}{4^n}\sin^4(2^nx))$ is

(A) $\sin^4x$

(B) $\sin^2x$

(C) $\cos^2x$

(D) does not exist

My attempt:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sin^4x+\frac{1}{4}\sin^4(2x)+\cdots+\frac{1}{4^n}\sin^4(2^nx))=$$
$$=(\sin^4x+\frac{1}{4}16\sin^4x\cos^4 x+\cdots+\frac{1}{4^n}\sin^4(2^{n-1}x)\cos^4(2^{n-1}x)$$

i could not solve further.Any hint will be useful.

Comment: Possible approach (for the lazy like me, that don't want to compute it exactly). This is a multiple choice question, can you eliminate possibilities?

 - $\lvert \sin \rvert \leq 1$, and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4^n}$ converges. Can it be **(D)**?
 - Plugging $x=0$, all terms are zero. Taking the limit, it should still be zero. Can it be **(C)**?

Comment: nice question....

Comment: @ClementC. Continuing with your approach, if $x$ is not a multiple of $\pi$, then the sum will be greater than the first term since all the terms are non-negative, and at least one will be positive. That takes care of (A).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$\sin^2y-\sin^4y=\sin^2y(1-\sin^2y)=\dfrac{\sin^22y}4$$

$y=x\implies$  $$\sin^2x-\sin^4x=\dfrac{\sin^22x}4$$

$y=2x\implies$  $$\dfrac{\sin^22x-\sin^42x}{4^1}=\dfrac{\sin^22x}{4^2}$$

Set $y=4x,2^rx$ and add to get

$$\sin^2x-\sum_{r=0}^n\dfrac{\sin^4(2^rx)}{4^r}=\dfrac{\sin^4(2^{n+1}x)}{4^{n+1}}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sin^4(2^{n+1}x)}{4^{n+1}}=0$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Note that $\sin^2 \theta - \sin^4\theta = \sin^2\theta(1-\sin^2\theta) = \sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta = \dfrac{1}{4}\sin^2 2\theta$.

Hence, $\sin^4\theta = \sin^2\theta - \dfrac{1}{4}\sin^2 2\theta$.

Applying that here gives us $\dfrac{1}{4^k}\sin^4(2^k x) = \dfrac{1}{4^k}\sin^2(2^k x) - \dfrac{1}{4^{k+1}}\sin^2(2^{k+1}x)$.

So, we need to compute the limit of $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{4^k}\sin^4(2^k x)$ $=\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\left[\dfrac{1}{4^k}\sin^2(2^k x) - \dfrac{1}{4^{k+1}}\sin^2(2^{k+1}x)\right]$.

This is a telescoping sum.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align} \sin^2 (x) - \sin^4(x) &= \sin^2 (x) \cos^2(x) = \frac14 \sin^2(2x), \\
 \frac14 \sin^2 (2x) - \frac14 \sin^4(2x) &= \sin^2 (2x) \cos^2(2x) = \frac{1}{4^2} \sin^2(4x),\\
&\cdots \\
\frac{1}{4^{n}} \sin^2 (2^{n}x) - \frac{1}{4^{n}} \sin^4(2^{n}x) &= \sin^2 (2^{n}x) \cos^2 (2^{n}x)= \frac{1}{4^{n+1}} \sin^2(2^{n+1} x). 
\end{align}
$$
So , the limit 
$$ \begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sin^4x+\frac{1}{4}\sin^4(2x)+\cdots+\frac{1}{4^n}\sin^4(2^nx)) &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( \sin^2 (x) - \frac{1}{4^{n+1}} \sin^2(2^{n+1} x) \right) \\
&=  \sin^2 (x) .
\end{align}$$

If you do not know this. For your multiple choice question:

1. Set $x = 0$. the limit (if exists) is $0$, so C is false.
2. For all $n$, $|\frac{1}{4^n}\sin(2^n x)| \leqslant \frac{1}{4^n}$ , thus by dominated convergence theorem, the sequence uniformly converges to a continues function, say $g(x)$. D is false.
3. Choose an $x_0 \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ such that $\frac13 <\sin^4(2x_0) < 1$, then $\frac14 \sin^4(2x_0)$ is strictly superior to the sum of the absolute value of the rest of the terms (which exists since the series is absolutely convergent and is inferior to $\frac{1}{12}$ by a simple comparison). So $|g(x_0) - \sin^4(x_0)| \geqslant \frac14 \sin^4(2x_0) - \sum|\mbox{rest of the terms}| > 0$.   So A is false.

So B is the only correct choice.

Comment: Your reasoning is flawed. The limit comes **after** the choice of $x$, and no positive choice of $x$ is small enough so that $2^n x < π$ for any $n$.

Comment: @user21820: you are right. A strict reasoning should base on the fact that the series is uniformly convergent and use a limit-summation switch.

Comment: Well okay, but there are much simpler ways; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution without any calculation**

Firstly, the limit exists because the absolute value of the terms are bounded by a geometric progression, so the partial sums form a Cauchy sequence and hence converges. Secondly, substituting $x = \frac{π}{2}$ and $x = \frac{π}{4}$ eliminates the wrong answers immediately.

Comment: Very clever, but this doesn't distinguish between (A) and (B).

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I typed wrongly...

Comment: Probably, but this doesn't distinguish between (B) and (C).

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Oh oops so careless. I was using both values not just one of them. =S

Comment: Anyway the general idea is to substitute something that cancels out all the terms except the first few so that the limit is trivial.